# Принцип браузерной игры в линукс терминале

Tags: java, linux, terminal

Наткнулся на `Java` библиотеку [CHARVA](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/).

И хотел бы уточнить у знающих людей, возможно ли на основе данной библиотеки сделать программу по принципу браузерной игры, но в место браузера - консоль, а в место `HTML` библиотека `CHARVA`?

Чтобы когда человек через линукс терминал присоединялся к моему серверу, в окне его терминала рисовалась моя программа?

Например какие нибудь банальные крестики нолики по сети, чтобы не нужно было загружать какой то клиент этой самой программы.

Начал обсуждение данной темы на [другом](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java/thread1829568.html) ресурсе, возможно оно поможет понять суть данного вопроса более полно.

Comment: на этот вопрос есть два ответа да или нет.